# Does Android 6 (Marshmallow) have JIT enabled by default?

Tags: android, jit, dex2oat

I have a question regarding the build method used in version 6 of the Android platform. I have a rooted LG Nexus 5,running version 6.0.1, and I am conducting a performance study of Android applications, where I run applications several times and observe their behavior throughout the tests. The following image shows examples of the standard behavior I am getting for all applications:
[evolution of energy performance throughout 25 tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfZBh.png)

Starting with version 5, Android reportedly started using AOT build instead of JIT. However, from what I have read, this is not always true, there are situations in which not all application code is compiled AOT and JIT is used to profiling code and optimizing its execution at runtime. After looking at the results obtained, it seems that there are runtime optimizations to be made on the applications and their code. Can these optimizations be made due to JIT?

When I invoke the following command using ADB, I get no return value:

```
 $ adb shell getprop dalvik.vm.usejit
```

Does this mean that JIT is disabled, or should it appear 'false'? What is the default value for this version?